# GitHub Azure Continuous Deployment Failing with Nuget Timeout

Tags: azure, github, nuget, continuous-deployment, nuget-package-restore

I have a project that works perfectly on my local machine. I am now trying to set to deploy via Continuous Deployment with Azure. I am using free Azure Websites tier and have pointed it at my GitHub repo. It finds the repo without issues and tries to get packages from Nuget.

The NuGet package restore fails with Http Timeout

> HTTP request timed out. Retrying.

I am using standard nuget feed so assume it isn't a NuGet issue directly. I am guessing that for some reason either the free instance can't handle this number of Nuget downloads at once? Is it possible to limit number of nuget download attempts? Any ideas?

When I deploy via GitHub it just fails with this in log:

```
   Command: "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"
Handling ASP.NET 5 Web Application deployment.
'dnx-coreclr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-update1' is already installed in D:\local\UserProfile\.dnx\runtimes\dnx-coreclr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-update1.
Adding D:\local\UserProfile\.dnx\runtimes\dnx-coreclr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-update1\bin to process PATH
Microsoft .NET Development Utility CoreClr-x86-1.0.0-rc1-16231

  CACHE https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
Restoring packages for D:\home\site\repository\src\MVC6Awakens\project.json
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/automapper/index.json
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/entityframework.core/index.json
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/entityframework.commands/index.json
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/entityframework.microsoftsqlserver/index.json
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.aspnet.authentication.cookies/index.json
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.aspnet.diagnostics.entity/index.json
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.aspnet.identity.entityframework/index.json
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.aspnet.iisplatformhandler/index.json
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.aspnet.mvc/index.json
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.aspnet.mvc.taghelpers/index.json
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.aspnet.server.kestrel/index.json
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.aspnet.staticfiles/index.json
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.aspnet.tooling.razor/index.json
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.extensions.codegenerators.mvc/index.json
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.extensions.configuration.fileproviderextensions/index.json
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.extensions.configuration.json/index.json
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.extensions.configuration.usersecrets/index.json
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.extensions.logging/index.json
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.extensions.logging.console/index.json
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.extensions.logging.debug/index.json
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.visualstudio.web.browserlink.loader/index.json
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/humanizer/index.json
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/fluentvalidation/index.json
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.net.http.server/index.json
Warning: FindPackagesById: AutoMapper
  HTTP request timed out. Retrying.
Warning: FindPackagesById: EntityFramework.Core
  HTTP request timed out. Retrying.
Warning: FindPackagesById: EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer
  HTTP request timed out. Retrying.
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/automapper/index.json
Warning: FindPackagesById: EntityFramework.Commands
  HTTP request timed out. Retrying.
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/entityframework.microsoftsqlserver/index.json
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/entityframework.core/index.json
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/entityframework.commands/index.json
Warning: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc
  HTTP request timed out. Retrying.
Warning: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers
  HTTP request timed out. Retrying.
Warning: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework
  HTTP request timed out. Retrying.
Warning: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler
  HTTP request timed out. Retrying.
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.aspnet.mvc/index.json
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.aspnet.mvc.taghelpers/index.json
Warning: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity
  HTTP request timed out. Retrying.
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.aspnet.iisplatformhandler/index.json
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.aspnet.identity.entityframework/index.json
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.aspnet.diagnostics.entity/index.json
Warning: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Cookies
  HTTP request timed out. Retrying.
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.aspnet.authentication.cookies/index.json
Warning: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileProviderExtensions
  HTTP request timed out. Retrying.
Warning: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.Extensions.CodeGenerators.Mvc
  HTTP request timed out. Retrying.
Warning: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json
  HTTP request timed out. Retrying.
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.extensions.configuration.fileproviderextensions/index.json
Warning: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor
  HTTP request timed out. Retrying.
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.extensions.codegenerators.mvc/index.json
Warning: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles
  HTTP request timed out. Retrying.
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.extensions.configuration.json/index.json
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.aspnet.tooling.razor/index.json
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.aspnet.staticfiles/index.json
Warning: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel
  HTTP request timed out. Retrying.
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.aspnet.server.kestrel/index.json
Warning: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.Net.Http.Server
  HTTP request timed out. Retrying.
Warning: FindPackagesById: Humanizer
  HTTP request timed out. Retrying.
Warning: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader
  HTTP request timed out. Retrying.
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.net.http.server/index.json
Warning: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug
  HTTP request timed out. Retrying.
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/humanizer/index.json
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.visualstudio.web.browserlink.loader/index.json
Warning: FindPackagesById: FluentValidation
  HTTP request timed out. Retrying.
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.extensions.logging.debug/index.json
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/fluentvalidation/index.json
Warning: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console
  HTTP request timed out. Retrying.
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.extensions.logging.console/index.json
Warning: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets
  HTTP request timed out. Retrying.
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.extensions.configuration.usersecrets/index.json
Warning: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.Extensions.Logging
  HTTP request timed out. Retrying.
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.extensions.logging/index.json
Warning: FindPackagesById: EntityFramework.Commands
  HTTP request timed out. Retrying.
Warning: FindPackagesById: EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer
  HTTP request timed out. Retrying.
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/entityframework.commands/index.json
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/entityframework.microsoftsqlserver/index.json
Warning: FindPackagesById: AutoMapper
  HTTP request timed out. Retrying.
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/automapper/index.json
Warning: FindPackagesById: EntityFramework.Core
  HTTP request timed out. Retrying.
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/entityframework.core/index.json
Warning: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Cookies
  HTTP request timed out. Retrying.
Warning: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity
  HTTP request timed out. Retrying.
Warning: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework
  HTTP request timed out. Retrying.
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.aspnet.authentication.cookies/index.json
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.aspnet.diagnostics.entity/index.json
Warning: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers
  HTTP request timed out. Retrying.
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.aspnet.identity.entityframework/index.json
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.aspnet.mvc.taghelpers/index.json
Warning: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler
  HTTP request timed out. Retrying.
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.aspnet.iisplatformhandler/index.json
Warning: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc
  HTTP request timed out. Retrying.
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.aspnet.mvc/index.json
Warning: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor
  HTTP request timed out. Retrying.
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.aspnet.tooling.razor/index.json
Warning: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel
  HTTP request timed out. Retrying.
Warning: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles
  HTTP request timed out. Retrying.
Warning: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.Extensions.CodeGenerators.Mvc
  HTTP request timed out. Retrying.
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.aspnet.server.kestrel/index.json
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.aspnet.staticfiles/index.json
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.extensions.codegenerators.mvc/index.json
Warning: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json
  HTTP request timed out. Retrying.
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.extensions.configuration.json/index.json
Warning: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileProviderExtensions
  HTTP request timed out. Retrying.
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.extensions.configuration.fileproviderextensions/index.json
Warning: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console
  HTTP request timed out. Retrying.
Warning: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets
  HTTP request timed out. Retrying.
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.extensions.logging.console/index.json
Warning: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.Extensions.Logging
  HTTP request timed out. Retrying.
Warning: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug
  HTTP request timed out. Retrying.
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.extensions.configuration.usersecrets/index.json
Warning: FindPackagesById: FluentValidation
  HTTP request timed out. Retrying.
Warning: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader
  HTTP request timed out. Retrying.
Warning: FindPackagesById: Humanizer
  HTTP request timed out. Retrying.
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.extensions.logging/index.json
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.extensions.logging.debug/index.json
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/fluentvalidation/index.json
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.visualstudio.web.browserlink.loader/index.json
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/humanizer/index.json
Warning: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.Net.Http.Server
  HTTP request timed out. Retrying.
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.net.http.server/index.json
Error: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework
----------
  HTTP request timed out. Exiting.
System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
Error: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
  HTTP request timed out. Exiting.
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Error: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
  HTTP request timed out. Exiting.
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Tooling.Restore.NuGet.HttpSource.<GetAsync>d__11.MoveNext()
Error: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  HTTP request timed out. Exiting.
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
Error: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Cookies
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
  HTTP request timed out. Exiting.
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
Error: FindPackagesById: AutoMapper
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Tooling.Restore.NuGet.NuGetv3Feed.<FindPackagesByIdAsyncCore>d__14.MoveNext()
  HTTP request timed out. Exiting.
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
Error: FindPackagesById: EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
  HTTP request timed out. Exiting.
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Error: FindPackagesById: EntityFramework.Commands
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Tooling.RemoteWalkProvider.<FindLibrary>d__6.MoveNext()
  HTTP request timed out. Exiting.
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
Error: FindPackagesById: EntityFramework.Core
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
  HTTP request timed out. Exiting.
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Error: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Tooling.RestoreOperations.<FindLibrary>d__9.MoveNext()
  HTTP request timed out. Exiting.
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
Error: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileProviderExtensions
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
  HTTP request timed out. Exiting.
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Error: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
  HTTP request timed out. Exiting.
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Tooling.RestoreOperations.<FindLibraryByVersion>d__8.MoveNext()
Error: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  HTTP request timed out. Exiting.
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
Error: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
  HTTP request timed out. Exiting.
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
Error: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.Extensions.CodeGenerators.Mvc
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Tooling.RestoreOperations.<FindLibraryMatch>d__6.MoveNext()
  HTTP request timed out. Exiting.
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
Error: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
  HTTP request timed out. Exiting.
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Error: FindPackagesById: Humanizer
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Tooling.RestoreOperations.<FindLibraryEntry>d__5.MoveNext()
  HTTP request timed out. Exiting.
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
Error: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.Extensions.Logging
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
  HTTP request timed out. Exiting.
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Error: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.Net.Http.Server
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
  HTTP request timed out. Exiting.
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Tooling.RestoreOperations.<CreateGraphNode>d__2.MoveNext()
Error: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  HTTP request timed out. Exiting.
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
Error: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
  HTTP request timed out. Exiting.
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
Error: FindPackagesById: FluentValidation
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Tooling.RestoreOperations.<CreateGraphNode>d__2.MoveNext()
  HTTP request timed out. Exiting.
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
Error: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
  HTTP request timed out. Exiting.
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Error: FindPackagesById: Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Tooling.RestoreCommand.<CreateGraphNode>d__71.MoveNext()
  HTTP request timed out. Exiting.
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Tooling.RestoreOperations.<FindLibraryEntry>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Tooling.RestoreCommand.<RestoreForProject>d__69.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Tooling.RestoreCommand.<>c__DisplayClass68_0.<<Execute>b__2>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Tooling.RestoreCommand.<Execute>d__68.MoveNext()
----------
Restore failed
A task was canceled.

NuGet Config files used:
    D:\home\site\repository\nuget.config

Feeds used:
    https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/
An error has occurred during web site deployment.
```

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: Nope. Just stopped doing it

Comment: I am facing the same even in my dev machine. VS 2015 Update 1 in Win 8